# How to type an array of Promises of various types in TS?

Tags: typescript

Given two promises - one that needs to be executed every time and one that needs to be executed only if a condition is met - that I want to execute asynchronously, how do I ensure that return type of `Promise.all` for each value is correct?

Here's an implementation that I thought should work:

```
type Promises = [Promise<string>, Promise<number>?]

const promises: Promises = [Promise.resolve('Lorem')]

if (someCondition) {
  promises.push(Promise.resolve(1))
}

// 'resolvedString' should be string
// 'resolvedNumber' should be number | undefined
const [resolvedString, resolvedNumber] = await Promise.all(promises)
```

but there are two issues with this code:

- Value of `resolvedNumber` is `number` and not `number | undefined` according to VSCode
- TS doesn't compile because of following error:

```
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Promises' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<string | PromiseLike<string>>'.
      The types returned by '[Symbol.iterator]().next(...)' are incompatible between these types.
        Type 'IteratorResult<Promise<string> | Promise<number>, any>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<string | PromiseLike<string>, any>'.
          Type 'IteratorYieldResult<Promise<string> | Promise<number>>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<string | PromiseLike<string>, any>'.
            Type 'IteratorYieldResult<Promise<string> | Promise<number>>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorYieldResult<string | PromiseLike<string>>'.
              Type 'Promise<string> | Promise<number>' is not assignable to type 'string | PromiseLike<string>'.
                Type 'Promise<number>' is not assignable to type 'string | PromiseLike<string>'.
                  Type 'Promise<number>' is not assignable to type 'PromiseLike<string>'.
                    Types of property 'then' are incompatible.
                      Type '<TResult1 = number, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: (value: number) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>, onrejected?: (reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<TResult2>) => Promise<...>' is not assignable to type '<TResult1 = string, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: (value: string) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>, onrejected?: (reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<TResult2>) => PromiseLike<...>'.
                        Types of parameters 'onfulfilled' and 'onfulfilled' are incompatible.
                          Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
                            Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.

93           const [resolvedString, resolvedNumber] = await Promise.all(promises)
```

TypeScript version is 4.3.5

Comment: [I see no problem](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQrqepAngO2GgDNEAKAShQyxoBccAHAU2gAUAneAWwEsImYAXmgBtDtz5MAPBFrseeAOYA+ADRtOvflLwBXLgCMm7ZQH4Auuho1g8PLOgNNkiAC4NE-kNHitTAHTsAvAgAG5MpADkADLwQVyR5JbU1tA8RNCkcrpMlGipqU6eAv4MuhAAFqS+koHBYREAjOTkKdYAvlYFtva0okEQIeEAJgDKcgqK6gNDTMMAcvpG7ObQwmAA7mA8fTX8-mAgIKRFfhCtNJ3tQA)

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler Interesting - I'm using TS v4.3.5 [in which the issue is present](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQrqepAngO2GgDNEAKAShQyxoBccAHAU2gAUAneAWwEsImYAXmgBtDtz5MAPBFrseeAOYA+ADRtOvflLwBXLgCMm7ZQH4Auuho1g8PLOgNNkiAC4NE-kNHitTAHTsAvAgAG5MpADkADLwQVyR5JbU1tA8RNCkcrpMlGipqU6eAv4MuhAAFqS+koHBYREAjOTkKdYAvlYFtva0okEQIeEAJgDKcgqK6gNDTMMAcvpG7ObQwmAA7mA8fTX8-mAgIKRFfhCtNJ3tQA)

Comment: Why are you on 4.3.5?

Comment: Your provided example indeed does not compile, but the types are as you expected them to be.

Comment: @kelly Just because we haven't updated dependencies in a while tbh ...

Comment: @MikeS. They're not in v4.3.5 - see the provided link please. The only reason for it not to compile in v4.7.5 could be that `someCondition` is not defined or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug/feature that [has been fixed on TS 4.5](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#the-awaited-type-and-promise-improvements).

Comment: Well you're base code is by far better than what I propose, but with your ts version, mine is the one you have to go with I believe

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I get the problem right, but, you can basically set several types in your promise, I believe this could help?

Such a type would allow your array to contain several Promises of "different" types. You could eventually Promise.all on this entire array?

```
const promises: Promise<string | number>[] = [Promise.resolve('Lorem')]
if (someCondition) {
  promises.push(Promise.resolve(1))
}
```

Comment: While this works, type of both `resolvedString` and `resolvedNumber` will be `string | number` which is not what I want - the real use case resolves DTO objects on which I need to access some properties and union doesn't allow me to do that.